# What context does the scheduler code run in?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduling, interrupt

There are two cases where the scheduler code `schedule()` is invoked-

1. When a process voluntarily calls `schedule()`
2. Timer interrupt calls `schedule()`

In case 2, I think `schedule()` runs in interrupt context, but what about the first case? Does it run in the context of the process which invoked it?

Also are there any more scenarios which invoke `schedule()`?

Comment: There's another case in which schedule() will be invoked: when a process blocks (for example due to I/O operation).

Comment: @omer It is the timer interrupt that call schedule() when process blocks. so your case is the same to case 2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`schedule()` always runs in process context.  In the second case, when it is initiated by a timer interrupt, it is in the return path back from the kernel to the interrupted process where `schedule()` is called.

Comment: Well schedule() happens as a system call which is just a trap interrupt AFAIK right?

Comment: @Jesus Ramos: "process context" and "interrupt context" are Linux kernel development terms that describe the context of code that is executing in kernel space: whether it can be regarded as executing on behalf of a particular process (as in a system call) or alteratively servicing a hardware interrupt.

Comment: Yeah I know the terminology the thing is that it was kind of confusing in this sense because a system call is technically an interrupt so I'm not sure if that's what he meant or the way the call actually gets executed.

Comment: @Jesus Ramos: It doesn't make sense to categorise things on how the kernel was entered, because it's *always* entered by means of an interrupt of some sort.  `schedule()` itself is always a codepath executing on behalf of the process to be scheduled-out, even if the kernel was entered via a timer interrupt - which means process context.

Comment: @JesusRamos: anyway, the traditional (non-Intel) terminology would be: interrupt (from a device), trap/syscall (from software), exception/fault (any of the former + from the CPU). Intel would be: exception/fault (from CPU), interrupt(from anywhere).

Answer (score 3):

__schedule() is the main scheduler function.

The main means of driving the scheduler and thus entering this function are:

1. Explicit blocking: mutex, semaphore, waitqueue, etc.
2. TIF_NEED_RESCHED flag is checked on interrupt and userspace return paths. For example, see arch/x86/entry_64.S. To drive preemption between tasks, the scheduler sets the flag in timer interrupt handler scheduler_tick().
3. Wakeups don't really cause entry into schedule(). They add a task to the run-queue and that's it. Now, if the new task added to the run-queue preempts the current task, then the wakeup sets TIF_NEED_RESCHED and schedule() gets called on the nearest possible occasion:

   - If the kernel is preemptible (CONFIG_PREEMPT=y):

     - in syscall or exception context, at the next outmost preempt_enable(). (this might be as soon as the wake_up()'s spin_unlock()!)
     - in IRQ context, return from interrupt-handler to preemptible context
   - If the kernel is not preemptible (CONFIG_PREEMPT is not set) then at the next:

     - cond_resched() call
     - explicit schedule() call
     - return from syscall or exception to user-space
     - return from interrupt-handler to user-space

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/core.c#L2389

Answer (score 0):

When a process calls `schedule()` it runs in a system call context which is interrupt based. In the 2nd case a hardware interrupt triggers the `schedule()` call. In both cases it runs as an interrupt. AFAIK those are the only times that `schedule()` is called because most manipulation of scheduling involves modifying the kernel run queue of things to be scheduled although a process can be interrupted but that is usually done via an interrupt to tell the process to yield or the process yielding itself.