# Kernel crash - NULL pointer dereference when calling DEVICE_WRITE from KTHREAD in a USB device driver

Tags: drivers, usb, multithreading

I'm writing a simple USB driver to drive a stepper motor based on USB Skeleton 2.2 Driver, kernel 3.8. The basic version is running properly. As a advancement, I introduced KTHREAD to call the DEVICE_WRITE (skel_write) (), so that the driver will be available for other tasks & requests.

```
Calling procedure : USER (request) -> DEVICE_IOCTL -> KTHREAD -> DEVICE_WRITE.
```

In this scenario, when I call the DEVICE_WRITE multiple times from KTHREAD through a loop, everything works fine. Then after some iterations, kernel gets messed up, Otherwise if called directly works fine. Upon seeing the log file, **the error is**  :

```
Dec 30 01:15:14 mit kernel: [  962.316843] device_write(efed1180,2,10),ioused : 1
Dec 30 01:15:14 mit kernel: [  962.316900] data : 0, motor_cnt : 2, master_counter : 20
Dec 30 01:15:14 mit kernel: [  962.366498] data : 1, motor_cnt : 2, master_counter : 21
Dec 30 01:15:14 mit kernel: [  962.416116] Write over, going for sleep
Dec 30 01:15:14 mit kernel: [  962.416125] file : efed1180,data : 2,i : 11
Dec 30 01:15:14 mit kernel: [  962.416128] device_write(efed1180,2,10),ioused : 1
Dec 30 01:15:14 mit kernel: [  962.416166] BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at   (null)
Dec 30 01:15:14 mit kernel: [  962.416254] IP: [] skel_write+0xd7/0x360 [usbstep]
Dec 30 01:15:14 mit kernel: [  962.416294] *pdpt = 0000000000000000* pde= f0002accf0002acc
Dec 30 01:15:14 mit kernel: [  962.416332] Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP
Dec 30 01:15:14 mit kernel: [  962.416363] Modules linked in: usbstep(OF) parport_pc(F) ppdev(F)   bnep rfcomm bluetooth snd_hda_codec_hdmi uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core videodev snd_hda_codec_idt coretemp snd_hda_intel kvm snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep(F) snd_pcm(F) snd_page_alloc(F) joydev(F) snd_seq_midi(F) snd_seq_midi_event(F) snd_rawmidi(F) hp_wmi lib80211_crypt_tkip snd_seq(F) snd_seq_device(F) snd_timer(F) sparse_keymap radeon wl(POF) lib80211 ttm drm_kms_helper cfg80211 drm hp_accel lis3lv02d mei input_polldev wmi i2c_algo_bit video(F) intel_ips mac_hid snd(F) lpc_ich soundcore(F) microcode(F) lp(F) parport(F) psmouse(F) serio_raw(F) r8169 ahci(F) libahci(F) [last unloaded: usbstep]
Dec 30 01:15:14 mit kernel: [  962.416866] Pid: 2997, comm: mitesh Tainted: PF          O 3.8.0-26-generic #38-Ubuntu Hewlett-Packard HP ProBook 4520s/1411
Dec 30 01:15:14 mit kernel: [  962.416928] EIP: 0060:[] EFLAGS: 00010287 CPU: 2
Dec 30 01:15:14 mit kernel: [  962.416960] EIP is at skel_write+0xd7/0x360 [usbstep]
Dec 30 01:15:14 mit kernel: [  962.416989] EAX: f0665b84 EBX: 00000014 ECX: 000000d0 EDX: 00000014
Dec 30 01:15:14 mit kernel: [  962.417024] ESI: f0665b40 EDI: 00000000 EBP: efddbf40 ESP: efddbf04
Dec 30 01:15:14 mit kernel: [  962.417059]  DS: 007b ES: 007b FS: 00d8 GS: 00e0 SS: 0068
Dec 30 01:15:14 mit kernel: [  962.417089] CR0: 8005003b CR2: 00000000 CR3: 019d1000 CR4: 000007f0
Dec 30 01:15:14 mit kernel: [  962.417124] DR0: 00000000 DR1: 00000000 DR2: 00000000 DR3: 00000000
Dec 30 01:15:14 mit kernel: [  962.417158] DR6: ffff0ff0 DR7: 00000400
Dec 30 01:15:14 mit kernel: [  962.417181] Process mitesh (pid: 2997, ti=efdda000 task=f0bed9b0 task.ti=efdda000)
Dec 30 01:15:14 mit kernel: [  962.417223] Stack:
Dec 30 01:15:14 mit kernel: [  962.417236]  f0665b84 efddbf58 efddbf58 0000000a 00000001 efddbf58 00000000 efddbf40
Dec 30 01:15:14 mit kernel: [  962.417301]  c1609d81 00000002 f06c5d40 00000014 0000000c efddbf58 f1487408 efddbf6c
Dec 30 01:15:14 mit kernel: [  962.417398]  f8585546 00000000 efed1180 efddbf58 0000000b f6eb0032 aa092dff f6eb7ebc
Dec 30 01:15:14 mit kernel: [  962.417475] Call Trace:
Dec 30 01:15:14 mit kernel: [  962.417504]  [] ? printk+0x4d/0x4f
Dec 30 01:15:14 mit kernel: [  962.417559]  [] tele+0x86/0xc0 [usbstep]
Dec 30 01:15:14 mit kernel: [  962.417618]  [] ? skel_write+0x360/0x360 [usbstep]
Dec 30 01:15:14 mit kernel: [  962.417691]  [] kthread+0x94/0xa0
Dec 30 01:15:14 mit kernel: [  962.417744]  [] ? __hrtimer_start_range_ns+0x2e0/0x460
Dec 30 01:15:14 mit kernel: [  962.417819]  [] ret_from_kernel_thread+0x1b/0x28
Dec 30 01:15:14 mit kernel: [  962.417886]  [] ? kthread_create_on_node+0xc0/0xc0
Dec 30 01:15:14 mit kernel: [  962.417951] Code: c0 89 c6 0f 84 83 01 00 00 83 c3 0a b8 00 0e 00 00 81 fb 00 0e 00 00 b9 d0 00 00 00 0f 46 c3 89 45 f0 8d 46 44 8b 55 f0 89 04 24 <8b> 07 e8 52 9f ee c8 85 c0 89 45 e4 0f 84 0f 01 00 00 8d 47 54
Dec 30 01:15:14 mit kernel: [  962.418433] EIP: [] skel_write+0xd7/0x360 [usbstep] SS:ESP 0068:efddbf04
Dec 30 01:15:14 mit kernel: [  962.418530] CR2: 0000000000000000
Dec 30 01:15:14 mit kernel: [  962.433930] ---[ end trace 63245eeeb64414aa ]---
```

Here goes the code : **KTHREAD**

```
int tele(void *__tele_data) {
        struct tele_data *tele_data = __tele_data;
        int i=0;
        char *dptr=NULL;
        char numb[4];
        sprintf(numb,"%d",tele_data->num);
        dptr=numb;
        for(i=0;i<30;i++) {
        is_ioctl_used=1;
                printk("file : %p,data : %s,i : %d\n", tele_data->file,dptr,i);
                skel_write(tele_data->file,(char *)dptr, 10, 0);
                printk("Write over, going for sleep\n");
        }
        return 0;
}
```

**DEVICE_WRITE -**

```
static ssize_t skel_write(struct file *file, const char *user_buffer,
                      size_t count, loff_t *ppos)
{
    struct usb_skel *dev;
    int retval = 0,i = 0,motor_count,dir=0;
    struct urb *urb = NULL;
    char *buf = NULL;
    char *buf1 = NULL;
    size_t writesize = min(count+10, (size_t)MAX_TRANSFER);
    printk(KERN_INFO "device_write(%p,%s,%d),ioused : %d\n", file, user_buffer, count,is_ioctl_used);
    dev = file->private_data;

    // verify that we actually have some data to write 
    if (count == 0)
            goto exit;

    /*
     * limit the number of URBs in flight to stop a user from using up all
     * RAM
     */

    if (!(file->f_flags & O_NONBLOCK)) {
            if (down_interruptible(&dev->limit_sem)) {
                    retval = -ERESTARTSYS;
                    goto exit;
            }
    } else {
            if (down_trylock(&dev->limit_sem)) {
                    retval = -EAGAIN;
                    goto exit;
            }
    }

    spin_lock_irq(&dev->err_lock);
    retval = dev->errors;
if (retval < 0) {
            // any error is reported once 
            dev->errors = 0;
            // to preserve notifications about reset 
            retval = (retval == -EPIPE) ? retval : -EIO;
    }
    spin_unlock_irq(&dev->err_lock);
    if (retval < 0)
            goto error;

    /* create a urb, and a buffer for it, and copy the data to the urb */
    buf1=(char *)kmalloc(sizeof(char)*20,GFP_KERNEL);  //Allocate 2nd buffer.
    if(is_ioctl_used) {   //Whether the write function is called from IOCTL or Directly (echo > /dev/stepper)
            sprintf(buf1,user_buffer);
    } else {
            if (copy_from_user(buf1, user_buffer,count)) {
                    retval = -EFAULT;
                    goto error;
            }
    }
    motor_count=simple_strtol(buf1,NULL,10);
    if(motor_count<0) {  //Rotation counts of stepper motor.
            motor_count=motor_count * -1;  //If motor_count<0 then rotate in anti-clock direction.
            dir=1;
    }
            urb = usb_alloc_urb(0, GFP_KERNEL);
            if (!urb) {
                    retval = -ENOMEM;
                    goto error;
            }

            buf = usb_alloc_coherent(dev->udev, writesize, GFP_KERNEL,
                            &urb->transfer_dma);
     if (!buf) {
                    retval = -ENOMEM;
                    goto error;
            }

            /* this lock makes sure we don't submit URBs to gone devices */
                    mutex_lock(&dev->io_mutex);
            if (!dev->interface) {          /* disconnect() was called */
                    mutex_unlock(&dev->io_mutex);
                    retval = -ENODEV;
                    goto error;
            }

            /* initialize the urb properly */
            usb_fill_int_urb(urb, dev->udev,
                            usb_sndintpipe(dev->udev, dev->bulk_out_endpointAddr),
                            buf, writesize, skel_write_bulk_callback, dev,dev->bInterval);
            urb->transfer_flags |= URB_NO_TRANSFER_DMA_MAP;
            usb_anchor_urb(urb, &dev->submitted);

    for(i=0;i<motor_count;i++) {  //Loop to rotate motor based on counts.
            printk("data : %d, motor_cnt : %d, master_counter : %d\n",ptr->data,motor_count,master_counter);
            if(dir==0) ptr=ptr->next;
            else ptr=ptr->prev;
            // Fill the buffers.
            buf[0]=0x01;
            buf[1]=0;
            buf[2]=ptr->data;

            /* send the data out the bulk port */
            retval = usb_submit_urb(urb, GFP_KERNEL);
    if (retval) {
                            dev_err(&dev->interface->dev,
                                            "%s - failed submitting write urb, error %d\n",
                                            __func__, retval);
                            mutex_unlock(&dev->io_mutex);
                            goto error_unanchor;

                    }
            if(++master_counter && master_counter > 47) master_counter=0;
            /*
             * release our reference to this urb, the USB core will eventually free
             * it entirely
             */
                            mdelay(50); //Delay is required to match with motor speed. 

            }
                    mutex_unlock(&dev->io_mutex);
                    usb_free_coherent(dev->udev, writesize, buf, urb->transfer_dma);
                    kfree(buf1);
                    usb_free_urb(urb);

                    is_ioctl_used=0;
            return writesize;
error_unanchor:
            usb_unanchor_urb(urb);
error:
    if (urb) {
            usb_free_coherent(dev->udev, writesize, buf, urb->transfer_dma);
            usb_free_urb(urb);
    }
    up(&dev->limit_sem);

exit:
    return retval;
}
```

I'm new to kernel programming and might be missing out something.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the root cause of your problem, but it seems like you have a number of issues in your `tele()` function:

```
    int tele(void *__tele_data) {
            struct tele_data *tele_data = __tele_data;
            int i=0;
            char *dptr=NULL;
            char numb[4];
            sprintf(numb,"%d",tele_data->num);
```

Here, you `sprintf()` the number into the numb buffer.  What is the range of `tele_data->num`?  Would it ever take more than 4 characters (including the terminating NUL character)?  Also, you're not recording how many bytes were printed in the buffer.  Seems like you'd want to know that for use below...

```
            dptr=numb;
```

Okay, so now `dptr` point to `numb`.  Which means it points to a character buffer that has a maximum of 4 bytes, but...

```
            for(i=0;i<30;i++) {
                    is_ioctl_used=1;
                    printk("file : %p,data : %s,i : %d\n", tele_data->file,dptr,i);
                    skel_write(tele_data->file,(char *)dptr, 10, 0);
```

In the `skel_write()` line above, you're requesting *10* bytes to be written.  That's 6 more than is available.  So you could be smashing the stack here.

I'm not convinced it's your only issue, but it does appear to be a problem.

Just a couple of other minor things to point out.  You don't need the cast on `dptr` in the `skel_write()` line... it's already a `char *`.  Be wary of casting as it can hide an unintentional mismatch of types if the type of the variable changes.  Also, the indentation in your code is all over the place.  I realize you're just learning, but get in the habit of good practices here.  It's really hard to read through your `skel_write()` implementation.  The are likely a few other issues there, and something as simple as correct indentation can help readers understand the flow, and potentially see the issue.

Finally, don't give up.  Kernel programming is hard: there are lots of moving parts, concurrency, locking, caching, and a very asynchronous style of programming.  OTOH, you're down close to the bare metal of your processor and system, and it's quite rewarding.

Comment: Hello John sir, Everything in skel_write was messing with kernel, passing the data was not the actual culprit.
I think calling skel_write() function was the mistake as every operation was leading to kernel crash after few successful operations.
So, finally I re-structured the code, put the initialization part of URB in probe as many drivers do and fired data(usb_submit_urb) from kthread and it worked fine.
My next attempt is to add a queue so that multiple requests will be stored in queue while the driver is busy serving current request.
Is it feasible enough to move on such type of driver?

Answer (score 0):

Mit,

May you need to scrutinize the kthreads behaviour w.r.t operations you are doing from inside it

See: [In what context Kernel Thread runs in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389688/in-what-context-kernel-thread-runs-in-linux)

Comment: Hello Sir,
   After going through all operations, I'm still uncertain about the exact reason cause almost every statement is causing an error. 1 thing I noticed that while writing to device via thread, if I switch tabs of terminal then kernel used to crash immediately. Sounds weird but kernel can change thread's state and running CPU which might be causing some issues. 
Calling skel_write() from thread was the mistake. So, I re-structured the code, put the initialization part of URB in probe as many drivers do and fired data(usb_submit_urb) from kthread and it worked fine.

Comment: My next attempt is to add a queue so that multiple requests will be stored in queue while the driver is busy serving current request. Is it feasible enough to move on such type of driver?